how to arrange containers of different sizes in div?
I am trying to arrange containers having fixed width but different heights inside a div. I tried using flexbox and the result is as follows

The height of any particular row is governed by item having the maximum height in that row. I need the items in the corresponding row to take up the extra space left by the items in the previous row, as can be seen in the following image

How can we do this?
